# Division by zero when the values are zero

Tags: php

I'm getting a warning "Division by zero"

this is the code

```
<p class='text-alert' id ="greet" align="left">Kill Death Ratio : <?php
$kd = $data['kills'] / $data['deaths'];
echo round($kd, 2);
?></p>
```

i guess i get it only when the kills and death values both are zero
Is there any possible solution

Comment: Are you familiar with `if` ?

Comment: Check if divider is zero and don't divide.

Comment: having a hard time which one to use as a duplicate. I'm being *wishy washy*.

Answer (score 2):

Just add an if statement before division

```
<p class='text-alert' id ="greet" align="left">Kill Death Ratio : <?php
if  ($data['deaths'] != 0){
$kd = $data['kills'] / $data['deaths'];
echo round($kd, 2);
}
else{
// Some other code which you want to run in case of zero
}
?></p>
```